# Jenkins build when multiple files are found

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to trigger a build with [Files Found Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Files+Found+Trigger) when multiple files are found in a certain directory?

For example:

[image]

The setting above is what I configured with Files Found Trigger.

The build is triggered when any one of the files (e.g. `a.txt` or `b.txt`) I specified exists. This is not the case I want.

How can I trigger the build only when both `a.txt` and `b.txt` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the source code of [Files Found Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin).

Hers's the [modified version](https://github.com/lyenliang/files-found-trigger-plugin):

[image]

Now the build is triggered only if the number of files found is greater than or equal to *Number of files found to tigger*.

But this modification makes some of the tests fail. I'll create a pull request once I fix this problem.

Here's the [pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin/pull/2).

Comment: Great contribution, and more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

This does not seem possible, when looking at how the search is performed in [`hudson.plugins.filesfoundtrigger.FileSearch#perform()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/files-found-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/filesfoundtrigger/FileSearch.java#L138-L142)

```
if (found.length == 1) {
      formValidation = FormValidation.ok(Messages.SingleFileFound(found[0]));
    } else {
      formValidation = FormValidation.ok(Messages.MultipleFilesFound(Integer
          .valueOf(found.length)));
}
```

You would need to setup a *separate* job which would create an `ac.txt` file if it detects both `a.txt` and `b.txt`, and would delete `ac.txt` otherwise.

That way, your current job can be triggered by a single file: `ac.txt`